# Passing a Variable to URL after form is processed

Tags: php, url

I'm currently working on a returns system design that is being added on to our current e-commerce system - and i'm stuck at the part where the order number variable is being passed to the thankyou page.

At the moment, the customer goes on to an order page, clicks on the return link (which sends them to a form), which is a set url with the order number dynamically added to the url. This order number is then sent from the form to a form processor, which emails us with the details of the order.

All works fine until the redirect to the thankyou page.

on the form, I have:

```
if(isset($_POST['submitted']))
 {
  if($formproc->ProcessForm())
 {
  $formproc->RedirectToURL();
 }
}
```

and in the form processor, I have :

```
function RedirectToURL()
{
$orderurl = $_POST['orderno'];

    $url = 'thank-you.php?returnreq=' . $orderurl;
    header("Location: $url");
    exit;
}
```

However, this returns no order number in the thank-you.php page url, despite the order number being passed correctly to the processor (as it sends an email with the correct order number inside)

Thanks for looking!

Comment: try to do a `var_dump($_POST)` in the RedirectToUrl() method and make sure you drop the `header` for testing. Perhaps the ordernr is unset somewhere or is case-sensitive.

Comment: Also check the debugging console in your browser to check the headers you're receiving.

Answer (score 1):

Check if $_POST['orderno'] is unset in ProcessForm method

Comment: i've checked and there is no variable unset in the processing of the form

Comment: Perhaps a rewrite rule removes this param ? or a router module ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to send the order number as a function param

```
function RedirectToURL($orderurl)
{
$url = 'thank-you.php?returnreq=' . $orderurl;
header("Location: $url");
exit;
}
```

change also from the fn call, like

```
....
$formproc->RedirectToURL($_POST["orderno"]);

....
```

Comment: Well in both the origional question and your answer the function name doesn't correctly represent what the function does.

Comment: unfortunately I still receive the URL without the orderurl/ordernumber attached!